# How to add try/catch to Future<void> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to debug the save function below. I tried to add a try/catch but in the catch I don't know how to return a null for a Future.

As I step through the code I get to the .doc(currentCleintId) and it exits. The currentClientid is the correct value so I don't know why it would fail.

```
  Future<void> saveClient(client, String currentClientid) {
    return _db.collection('client').doc(currentClientid).set(client);
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```dart
 Future<void> saveClient(client, String currentClientid) async {
    try {
       return await _db.collection('client').doc(currentClientid).set(client);
    } catch(e){
       print(e.toString();
       return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right.

Comment: This is no longer returning void.  If you had your analyzer properly cranked up (like using very_good_analysis, for example), you'd have to remove the two returns.